# Docker and libseccomp

Tags: security, docker, opensuse

I'm running into a problem with docker. I've got here OpenSuse 13.2 with a self-built version of libseccomp library. it's fresh version 2.3.1 from couple of weeks ago. If i'm running any docker container, i get the following error:

```
hostname:/usr/lib/docker # docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
78445dd45222: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "conditional filtering requires libseccomp version >= 2.2.1"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "conditional filtering requires libseccomp version >= 2.2.1".
ERRO[0002] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled
```

Of course i can use an option --security-opt seccomp:unconfined when starting a container, but this is not my purpose.

```
# rpm -qa libseccomp
libseccomp-2.3.1-1.x86_64
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-254:2-655361-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 307.2 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 20.64 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 806.9 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.147 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.03.01 (2011-10-15)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version:  (expected: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e)
runc version: N/A (expected: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e)
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.16.7-53-desktop
Operating System: openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.868 GiB
Name: hostname
ID: DCOH:JZMG:ZUTM:5MSB:DVAG:SQXS:Z36N:5OXU:GQII:YTMO:RWDA:HYBJ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Did you restart the docker daemon after upgrading libseccomp?

Comment: sure things. I have even restarted machine

Comment: Have you rebuilt `runc` using the new libseccomp version? In general I would recommend against these sorts of frankenbuilds -- there's a reason we publish and curate packages in OBS. It's to make these sorts of issues not happen.

Comment: Ok i'm going to try it out. The thing I don't understand is why the package like this: docker-1.13.0-182.1.x86_64  or  runc-0.1.1+gitr2942_2f7393a-33.2.x86_64 got into production and apparently has never been tested. It' not working out of the box on 13.2, because the latest available version of libseccomp for 13.2 is 2.1.1.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the problem may be with runc. I'm currently running into the same identical error, on Leap 42.1 with docker & runc from OBS Virtualization:containers repo. My setup was running fine until recent set of package updates.

```
i | runc   | package    | 0.1.1+gitr2942_2f7393a-33.2 | x86_64 | Virtualization:containers (openSUSE_Leap_42.1)
i | docker | package    | 1.13.0-182.1                | x86_64 | Virtualization:containers (openSUSE_Leap_42.1)
```

strings on /usr/sbin/runc show:

```
strings /usr/sbin/runc | grep 2.2.1
[..]
conditional filtering requires libseccomp version >= 2.2.1
[..]
```

Going down further, changelog shows:

```
* Fri Feb 24 2017 
- update to docker-1.13.0 requirement
* Mon Dec 19 2016 
- update runc to the version used in docker 1.12.5 (bsc#1016307).
```

And the source for that package has `Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang/seccomp_internal.go` with this on line 299:

```
return fmt.Errorf("conditional filtering requires libseccomp version >= 2.2.1")
```

Looks like there is now an official bug report, and this issue impacts a few different SUSE releases that use that repo:

https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1028639

Comment: you are right. I had same issue with Leap 42.1 and a recent update with Docker 1.13.0. I have to downgrade to Docker 1.12.6